# Selecting only one column in mongo db using morphia

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia, mongodb-java

I have 2 columns String id, String Name and long age.

As we would have done in sql - select id FROM USERDETAILS Where Age > 5 would give me arrayList of primary keys that is "Id".

can anyone tell me how to do the same for mongo db using morphia.

I tried with `query.retrieveFields(true,"id").get();`

but it returns a USERDETAILS Model in return , i need only array of ids. how can i do this please help

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/mongodb-extract-only-the-selected-item-in-array

Comment: Using morphia, queries always return your model class. In your case, the name and age fields will be empty/null. So you can iterator over list and the the ids in your java app.

Comment: yep i have used iterative method but their were some performance issues. any way of avoiding iteration ?

Comment: Well, you could use the java driver directly, but you have to transform a `DBCursor` in a `List<String>` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to get back your model class with morphia.  That's what it does.  If you want the raw list of IDs, you'll need to use the driver directly.

Answer (score 0):

use project

`Query<Object> query = createQuery(); query.project("fieldNamewhichisalonerequired", true); return query.asList();`